# 405 error while calling webapi get method using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

I developed a WebApi and Client page for testing.
Here is my controller

```
public class CarDetailsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/cardetails
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CarsStock > GetAllcarDetails()
    {
        CarsStock ST = new CarsStock();
        CarsStock ST1 = new CarsStock();
        List<CarsStock> li = new List<CarsStock>();

            ST.CarName = "Maruti Waganor";
            ST.CarPrice = "4 Lakh";
            ST.CarModel = "VXI";
            ST.CarColor = "Brown";
            li.Add(ST);

            ST1.CarName = "Maruti Swift";
            ST1.CarPrice = "5 Lakh";
            ST1.CarModel = "VXI";
            ST1.CarColor = "RED";
            li.Add(ST1);

        return li;  
    }
```

}

and here is my ajax call

```
    <button onclick="AllcarDetails()"></button>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function AllcarDetails()
        {
            $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "http://localhost:1822/api/cardetails", //URI   
            success: function (data) {  
                debugger;  
                var datadatavalue = data;  

            },  
            error: function (xhr) {  
                alert(xhr.responseText);  
            }  
    });  
        }
    </script>
```

It gives 405 Method Not Allowed error all the time.I tried by googling but cannot find the exact situation.Can somebody help me to solve this?

Got result correctly while calling from browser 'http://localhost:1822/api/cardetails'

Comment: so it works on a browser, but where isn't it working then? just a guess, try removing the headers.

Comment: While calling ajax GET method it gives error

Comment: i removed but still not working

Comment: I'm also guessing that ajax is running on the same server as the api, so change your url to this: `url: "/api/cardetails",`. Also make sure you are using `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]` attribute on your controller, not the `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]` one.

Comment: The url is changed to "http://localhost:8383/api/cardetails" but no response or error

Comment: you changed the url but still left localhost there with the wrong port this time (since everywhere else you are calling on port 1822) so if the port it's wrong, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check so that HTTP Activation is activated where you run this code?

Comment: While simply calling the uri in browser i can get the result but using ajax it gives 405 error